# Normalizing of _score field in a search query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-7

I want the **_score** field returned by elasticsearch to be in the range say **(0 to 100)**. Is there a way this can be done by the Elasticsearch, so that I don't have to do it manually in the code.